# NVidia GTX660 driver not working on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gpu, gpu-driver

I want to install tensorflow on Linux on a **Dell Inspiron 580** with an **NVidia GTX660** graphics card, so I need to install CUDA and cuDNN, but not only do they not work, but I can't even get the drivers properly. I tried in many system configurations:
- Ubuntu 16.04.5 Server with: {nvidia-396, nvidia-390, nvidia-340}
- Ubuntu 16.04.1 Server with: {nvidia-390, nvidia-340}
- Ubuntu 14.04 Server with: {nvidia-340, nvidia-304}
- Ubuntu 12.04 Server couldn't even install the drivers

Ubuntu 16.04 with nvidia-304 worked, but poorly - max available resolution was 1366x768 in a weird black frame, even though I have a Full HD display. Also, CUDA 9.2 didn't work and for CUDA 5.0 - version suitable for this driver, I couldn't find the way to install it on an up-to-date Ubuntu.

I tried installing nvidia drivers from official repos, also from ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa and from .run files from official NVidia page. This machine runs a standard American Megatrends BIOS, so no EFI and SecureBoot oriented issues.

I satisfy all the requirements mentioned [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/#pre-installation-actions).

I tried exact following of these tutorials (always from a fresh system install): [Charlie's blog](https://charlienewey.github.io/getting-nvidia-drivers-working-on-ubuntu-17-10/), [Puget systems](https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/The-Best-Way-To-Install-Ubuntu-16-04-with-NVIDIA-Drivers-and-CUDA-1097/)

On a nouveau driver, whichever Desktop Environment I chose, it displayed perfectly well: Full HD and without any errors. Also, the tty was nicer looking. With nvidia driver everything is in low resolution and DE doesn't even appear. I only see blinking cursor on `/dev/tty7`.

What can I do to get it working for tensorflow? I can change distro, software configuration, etc. I have stuck only with current hardware config. Also, it needs to be Linux. It can even be CUDA 5.0 if it means that would work.

Below there are diagnosis commands I used:

```
$ sudo lspci | grep -i nvidia
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK106 [GeForce GTX 660] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK106 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)


$ uname -m && cat /etc/*release
x86_64
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=17.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=artful
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 17.10"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="17.10 (Artful Aardvark)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 17.10"
VERSION_ID="17.10"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=artful
UBUNTU_CODENAME=artful


$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu3.2) 7.2.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.


$ uname -r
4.13.0-46-generic


$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GK106 [GeForce GTX 660]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:fa000000-faffffff memory:d8000000-dfffffff memory:d6000000-d7ffffff ioport:ec00(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff


$ dmesg | grep NVRM
[    4.441575] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  384.130  Wed Mar 21 03:37:26 PDT 2018 (using threaded interrupts)
[    9.338846] NVRM: failed to copy vbios to system memory.
[    9.339139] NVRM: RmInitAdapter failed! (0x30:0xffff:661)
[    9.339164] NVRM: rm_init_adapter failed for device bearing minor number 0
[   27.130008] NVRM: failed to copy vbios to system memory.
[   27.130401] NVRM: RmInitAdapter failed! (0x30:0xffff:661)
[   27.130516] NVRM: rm_init_adapter failed for device bearing minor number 0
[   28.086782] NVRM: failed to copy vbios to system memory.
[   28.087155] NVRM: RmInitAdapter failed! (0x30:0xffff:661)
[   28.087195] NVRM: rm_init_adapter failed for device bearing minor number 0
[   28.999220] NVRM: failed to copy vbios to system memory.
[   28.999665] NVRM: RmInitAdapter failed! (0x30:0xffff:661)
[   28.999735] NVRM: rm_init_adapter failed for device bearing minor number 0
[   29.914304] NVRM: failed to copy vbios to system memory.
[   29.914735] NVRM: RmInitAdapter failed! (0x30:0xffff:661)
[   29.914798] NVRM: rm_init_adapter failed for device bearing minor number 0
[   30.827998] NVRM: failed to copy vbios to system memory.
[   30.828413] NVRM: RmInitAdapter failed! (0x30:0xffff:661)
[   30.828544] NVRM: rm_init_adapter failed for device bearing minor number 0


$ nvidia-smi
No devices were found
```